# Local images no loading on React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

When i'm trying to display an image `<img src = {require(path)}/>` I dont know why, i dont get that images when i start the react app, althogh my partner on his computer can see the images. And I have deleted and installed all from his files.

The images on browser appears as `<img src = [Object Module]/>`. I've done some research, and it seems to be some problem with webpack or url-loader, but i dont understand why on my computers isnt working and in my parnert is.

If someone have an idea. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: import the image first in the top and then specify the src

Comment: Now when I use <img src = {require(path).default}/> it works. Any way to make it work without it ??

Answer (score 1):

Try to import the image first like this:

```
import image from '../image.jpg'

const App = () => {
   return (
     <img src={image} alt='image' />
   )
}
```

Comment: This worked but, is there any way that i could use require ?? 2 weeks ago, all stuff was worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna wrap the src value in braces

```js
<img src={require(path)} />
```

Comment: sorry i wrote it wrong on the post. On my code it is right